# disqus-comment-count isn't customizable

Tags: wordpress, disqus

I am trying to make Disqus work with WordPress (and vice versa).
Now when I show disqus comments number, I get [number] Comments. I want to delete word "Comments".
So, I go to Site Community Settings. I change text here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZUeO.png)

But I'm still having word "Comments" in page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone, who will meet that problem.
Just wait.

Answer (score 0):

```
Zero Comments      | 0<span style="display:none;">
One Comment        | 1<span style="display:none;">
Multiple Comments  | {num}<span style="display:none;">
```

Just tried it myself, it's working.